# How to get the updated list in main method

Tags: java, list

I am having a list of queues as follows:

```
public class QueueSelection {   
    public List initQueueCollection()   
    {   
        QueueLoad d1 = new QueueLoad("QUEUEA1", "QUEUEB1", true);   
        QueueLoad d2 = new QueueLoad("QUEUEA2", "QUEUEB2", false);   
        QueueLoad d3 = new QueueLoad("QUEUEA3", "QUEUEB3", true);   
        QueueLoad d4 = new QueueLoad("QUEUEA4", "QUEUEB4", false);   
        List list = new ArrayList();   
        list.add(d1);   
        list.add(d2);   
        list.add(d3);   
        list.add(d4);   

        return list;   
     }
```

Now from the main method, i call the above method like,

```
QueueSelection selection = new QueueSelection();   
List<QueueLoad> queueList =selection.initQueueCollection();
```

When the first input/file comes, queue is checked to see which one of these is `false`, so I am fetching the second one `("QUEUEA2", "QUEUEB2", false)`; 
As soon as I fetch it, I should change the status to `true` like `("QUEUEA2", "QUEUEB2", true)`; I am doing it using

```
for (QueueLoad s:queueList)   
{   
    if(s.getStatus()==false)   
    {   
        str1=s.getQueueName1();   
        str2=s.getQueueName2();   
        str3=s.getStatus();   
        particularCollection=s;   
        System.out.println(s);   
        particularCollection.setStatus(true);   
        particularCollection.setQueueName1(str1);   
        particularCollection.setQueueName2(str2);   
        int j=queueList.indexOf(particularCollection);   
        System.out.println("The index is"+j);   
        s = new QueueLoad(str1, str2, true);   
        newqueueList=queueList.set(j, s);
```

And the list is updated. Now when the second input comes, since in the first line it is seeing the `List<QueueLoad> queueList =selection.initQueueCollection()`; 
it is always getting the old list and not the updated one.

Please help.

Comment: that's because you are initializing it all the time. when you are executing this:  List list = new ArrayList();  in the initQueueCollection() method.

Comment: It is unclear from your question exactly where you are calling initQueueCollection(). For example, is it inside of a for loop?

Comment: @quazzieclodo i am calling initQueueCollection() outside the for loop.

Comment: You mentioned that initQueueCollection() is called more than once. From your question, I never see how that happens.

Comment: @quazzieclodo,I am calling the  initQueueCollection() when the new input comes. For every input that comes, each one will see the queue which has the status as "false", and make it as "true". My problem is once the List is updated to true, for the second input, the new list with updated status should be fetched so that the same queue which was fetched earlier should not be fetched again.

Comment: So you're looping through the inputs? Then put init outside of that loop...

Comment: @quazzieclodo i am calling initQueueCollection() outside the for loop only.

Comment: Just post your main code. The flow of your program is unclear from what you've written.

Comment: QueueSelection selection = new QueueSelection();List<QueueLoad> queueList =selection.initQueueCollection();for (QueueLoad s:queueList){if(s.getStatus()==false){str1=s.getQueueName1();str2=s.getQueueName2();str3=s.getStatus();particularCollection=s;particularCollection.setStatus(true);particularCollection.setQueueName1(str1);particularCollection.setQueueName2(str2);int j=list.indexOf(particularCollection);s = new QueueLoadProcess(str1, str2, true);

Comment: You said "I am calling the initQueueCollection() when the new input comes." However, no where in your code is it shown where that happens or where you get any input from. Until that is up, I can't help

Comment: @quazzieclodo In my main method I have the above code. I dont know how to restrict to call the queueList =selection.initQueueCollection() for the first call and from the next call get the updated list. And that is what I am looking for. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

> Now when the second input comes, since in the first line it is seeing
>   the List queueList =selection.initQueueCollection(); it is
>   always getting the old list and not the updated one.

I interpret this to mean that you don't want the init method to be invoked again '**when the second input comes**'.

There are a lot of ways to address this.  Have you considered moving the init method into the constructor for `QueueSelection`, for example?

Comment: @AmirAfgani public class QueueLoad {private String QueueName1;private String QueueName2;private Boolean Avail;public String getQueueName1(){return QueueName1;}public void setQueueName(String queueName1){QueueName1=queueName1;}public String getQueueName2(){return QueueName2;}public void setQueueName2(String queueName2){QueueName2=queueName2;}public Boolean getStatus(){return Avail;}public void setStatus(Boolean avail){Avail=avail;}public QueueLoadProcess(String queueName1,String queueName2, Boolean avail) {this.QueueName1 = queueName1;this.QueueName2 = queueName2;this.Avail = avail;}}

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29) for `ArrayList.set`. It returns the old value at that location. So you'll want to do:

```
queueList.set(j, s);
newqueueList = queuelist;
```

Comment: Yes I have done that also, but still how to I avoid calling List<QueueLoad> queueList =selection.initQueueCollection(); for further calls and get the newqueueList?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly then you're problem is that at each new input you are intializing a new list. Maybe just put queueList as class attribute?

Also:

```
    newqueueList=queueList.set(j, s);
```

I think set() returns the object that was previously at that index. So your newqueueList would actually contain a QueueLoad object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown your main() method, I'm not certain what it looks like, but something along these lines should work:

Instead of:

```
QueueSelection selection = new QueueSelection();   
List<QueueLoad> queueList =selection.initQueueCollection();
```

Declare queueList outside the method something like this:

```
private static List<QueueLoad> queueList = null;
```

Then, in the method,

```
if (queueList == null)
{
  QueueSelection selection = new QueueSelection();   
  queueList =selection.initQueueCollection();
}
```